# Bevel modifier not working properly

Tags: modifiers

I have an object on which I want to apply a bevel modifier. After applying, no matter how high I increase the Width, the bevel stays the same.

About the object:

1. I've imported a .svg and then converted it to 'Mesh from Curve'
2. In Edit Mode: Select all Faces → Mesh → Faces → Beautify Fill
3. Select all Faces → Mesh → Delete → Limited Dissolve
4. Then I extruded the Object and now I want to create a bevel

You can get the .blend file [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/hg0ih6phxl5tnhh/Bevel.blend).

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Anyone an Idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also directly apply a depth and extrude parameter to the Curve object. This keeps the curve object editable. And it gives cleaner result:

[image: Curve Datablock Editor]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 12):

The 'Clamp Overlap' option is enabled on the modifier. Un-check this to have a bigger bevel.

I would then suggest immediately setting the bevel back to 0 as the current value will be very large.

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging on the bevel width value to increase the value slowly.

Comment: Yes, that did it, but I the bevels are now really crazy. https://www.mediafire.com/?odjqx9m52bb2f9f I think the bevel modifier is a bit confused by the many vertices. You have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can try turning on the 'angle limit' option and this may help, but this may just be a limit of the modifier when trying to do a bevel that large.

Comment: @BlenderShark The *Clamp overlap* option makes sure bevels don't extrude through each other (as in your screenshot). Try leaving it enabled and selecting specific edges to be beveled (with bevel weight or vertex groups).

Answer (score 3):

The best result I could come up with was from using two bevel modifiers, with vertex groups to limit them to the outer or inner edges. Along with some small geometry changes this prevents the bevel being applied to edges spanning the flat surfaces or sides that was causing artifacts.

[image]

I also shaded smooth and added an edge split modifier. The modified file is available [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27224).